# List item header change background color onClick

Tags: html, css

How to change header list items color onClick?By default home item background color is green.When I click contact item or any other it should get background color green and home item shouldn't have green background anymore!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="art-main">
        <header class="art-header">
            <nav class="art-nav">
                <ul class="art-hmenu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>        
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


.art-header
{
   margin:0 auto;
   height: 100px;
   background-position: 19px 6px, 0 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 900px;
   z-index: auto !important;
}

.art-nav
{
   padding:5px 2px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   top:     20px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
   text-align: right;
}


ul.art-hmenu li
{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   background: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}

ul.art-hmenu 
{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li {
   margin-left: 2px;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li:first-child {
   margin-left: 1px;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li:last-child, ul.art-hmenu>li.last-child {
   margin-right: 1px;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a
{
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   height: 51px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #808080;
   line-height: 51px;
   text-align: center;
}

.art-hmenu>li>a, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:link, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:visited, 
.art-hmenu>li>a.active, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:hover
{
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: left;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a.active
{
   background: #73B078;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   -svg-background: linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid #57995C;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, .desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a
{
   background: #ADAF88;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   -svg-background: linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid #ADAF88;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, 
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: You would like to change the color of the button after you clicked on it AND then the page reloaded ?

Comment: No I don't want, just when clicked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery

```js
$('ul li a').click(function(){

    if ($('ul li a').hasClass("active")){
          $('ul li a').removeClass("active");
          }
  
     $(this).addClass("active");
    
 });
```

```css
.art-header
{
   margin:0 auto;
   height: 100px;
   background-position: 19px 6px, 0 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: auto !important;
}

.art-nav
{
   padding:5px 2px;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   top:     20px;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 100;
   text-align: right;
}


ul.art-hmenu li
{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 5;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   background: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 0;
}

ul.art-hmenu 
{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li {
   margin-left: 2px;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li:first-child {
   margin-left: 1px;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li:last-child, ul.art-hmenu>li.last-child {
   margin-right: 1px;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a
{
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid transparent;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   height: 51px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #808080;
   line-height: 51px;
   text-align: center;
}

.art-hmenu>li>a, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:link, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:visited, 
.art-hmenu>li>a.active, 
.art-hmenu>li>a:hover
{
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   text-align: left;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a.active
{
   background: #73B078;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   -svg-background: linear-gradient(top, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #93C297 0, #5CA362 85%, #56995C 100%) no-repeat;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid #57995C;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}

ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, .desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a
{
   background: #ADAF88;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   -svg-background: linear-gradient(top, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C2C3A7 0, #969867 100%) no-repeat;
   -webkit-border-radius:5px;
   -moz-border-radius:5px;
   border-radius:5px;
   border:1px solid #ADAF88;
   padding:0 22px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, 
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="art-main">
        <header class="art-header">
            <nav class="art-nav">
                <ul class="art-hmenu">
                    <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a>About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>        
        </header>
    </div>
```

Comment: you can add the script dirctly on your html **<script> your script here <script>** or include an external js for example navbar.js in this way **<script src="js/navbar.js"></script>**.You need to include the jquery library also as in my snippet(just copy the include script) to make it working. You need to insert js in this order 1st jquery library 2nd your js script.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

Comment: no, 1st, you need to add jquery library: **<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>** 2nd you need to place your script, if you have created a js file with the script inside in the same folder of html **<script src="yourscript.js">**

Comment: I added <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: and all files are in same folder

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you create html,css and jquery and upload them to mega or dropbox?

Comment: please follow this step by step guide:
1) include jquery library just before the end of your body tag **here</body>** , to do it just copy/paste my include script tag on my snippet

2)create a file navbar.js in the same index.html folder, put in the file the script that I've wrote and save it

3) come back to html. Immediately after the jquery library script closing tag **</script>here** place your js <script src="navbar.js"></script>**